# SQL assistance with displaying names who have 2 same letters. Gives error now

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

sorry to ask so many questions about SQL but I am doing exercises that help me revise for my test.

I am trying to display the names of all people who have 2 Ls in their name and are in depno = 30 or their super is "7782". I have written some code for it but its giving an error. I have used the Column name "SUPER" for the manager.

```
SELECT   ENAME
FROM     emp
WHERE    ENAME LIKE 'L%', DEPTNO = 30;
OR       SUPER = '7782';
```

**Thanks alot again!**

-Jay

Found the answer:
The answer should actually be:

```
SELECT   ENAME 
FROM     emp 
WHERE    ENAME LIKE '%L%L%' AND DEPTNO = 30
OR SUPER = '7782';
```

because the other codes given here give me an error as the end of third line is not supposed to have a semicolon.

Comment: 2 Continuous Ls like LLama? Or names with 2 Ls in them in total, like LiLy?

Comment: @DoozerBlake - Hi, the answer could have LOLA or MILLER. Hence, two Ls anywhere in the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT   ENAME 
FROM     emp 
WHERE    ENAME LIKE '%L%L%', DEPTNO = 30; 
OR       SUPER = '7782';
```

Be aware that the LIKE '%L' might prevent the usage of an index.

Answer (score 2):

`Select *
from yourtable
where name like '%L%L%'
or depno = 30
or super = 7782`

Comment: thought two letter L's not a double L?

Comment: That is specifically "Two L's next to each other".  `'%L%L%'` will allow for two L's in any position at all.

Comment: @Surfer513 - Thanks for your help guys, appreciate it